xcodebuild failed with code 65 on macOS Sonoma 14.5 M3 Pro
I'm continuously getting below error after starting ios session from appium inspector :
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message:
The capabilities that I have added are :
{
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 15 Pro",
"appium:udid": "E22AF327-F30B-4494-9897-6177EFFDEFC4",
"platformName": "iOS",
"appium:platformVersion": "17.5",
"appium:automationName": "XCUITest"
}
Below are the config:
macOS : Sonoma 14.5 (M3 Pro)
npm version : 10.7.0
node version : v20.15.0
appium version : 1.22.3
java version : 17.0.8
xcode version : 15.4
Simulator iOS version : 17.5
I know there are many solutions available to resolve this error, but none of them is working in my case.
I have recently started using M3 pro, earlier I was using M1 and things used to work perfectly fine.
Currently, the issue is only with ios session while the appium inspector works fine with android emulator.
Can someone please look into this issue and help in resolving please?
Thanks in advance.
enter image description here
I have tried all the solutions mentioned here : Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
but none of the solution worked.
